# Scroll to last row having class in jQuery Dialog on open

Tags: onload, jquery-dialog, scrolltop

Populating a jQuery UI Dialog with a longish table,  I would like to have it scroll to the last row in the table having a specific class.  I found two other posts almost identical to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888585/jquery-dialog-scroll-to-element-in-dialog), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905867/how-to-scroll-to-specific-item-using-jquery), but I can't get it to work.  I've mocked it up at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wallabykid/e6rDT/) in the hope that someone might help me see the error in my thinking on it.

Here is the basic code

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var content = jQuery('#amtz_div').html();
    var title = 'Amortization Schedule';
    var open = function() {
        var container = jQuery(".ui-dialog");
        var target = jQuery('tr.amortized:last');
        container.scrollTop(target.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop());
        target.css('background', 'red');
    }
    jQuery("#dialog").attr('title', title).html(content).dialog({
        modal: true,
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        resizable: false,
        open: open
    });
});
```

I also tried the scrollTo plugin (mentioned in one of the post linked above) but had now better luck with that.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if it's the new version of `jQuery UI` or that we have been away from this but changing the identifier from .ui-dialog to #dialog work in your case. I'm going to see if this works for me as well!

[solution](http://jsfiddle.net/e6rDT/4/)